# Handsontable cells merge functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I'm using Handsontable to display data from Excel and recently i've got a task to merge cells. But plugin doesnt have that functionality. I tried to make it myself but it reacts strangely. Algorithm is that i remove(splice) elements from table's data and then set appropriate colspan/rowspan for target cell. Did anybody have similar problem?

Comment: Are you removing the <td>s that are getting merged into the target <td>?

Comment: This is a feature being worked on. To follow the development and a possible suggested temporary solution, see https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/181

Comment: alxndr: no. just data. handsontable then rebuilds the table itself

Comment: PostureOfLearning: thanks, hope new f-lity comes soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handsontable now supports [merged cells](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.1/demo-merge-cells.html) (Introduced in Jul 2014; Version > 0.11).